# Event Handler as Wrapper for Async?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, event-handling, wrapper

Currently I have a `class` which contains another `class` which has an `Async` method

```
public class MyClass { //This is my user-defined class
    private HasASyncClass hasAsyncItem; //it has a class which has an Async method
}
```

Then, in the `MyClass` I make a wrapper for my `hasAsyncItem` like this

```
public void BeignAsyncWrapper() {

    //Do something for safe process and checking
    hasAsyncItem.BeginAsync(new AsyncCallback(endAsyncItemHandler), hasAsyncItem);
    //Do something else
}

private void endAsyncItemHandler (IASyncResult ar) {
    HasASyncClass asyncItem = ar.AsyncState as HasASyncClass;
    asyncItem.EndAsync(ar); 

    //and so on
}
```

Now, I have another `instance` which has `MyClass` and I want that `instance` to be aware if `endAsyncItemHandler` inside `MyClass` is entered.

My question is should I use `event handler` to "wrap" the `Async` event? Or should I wrap it using another `async` method?

Though I used `async` methods a couple of times in the past, this is the first time I am to make wrapper `class` for it. I am looking for inputs on how is it to be done correctly - especially in the cross-thread context where `MyClass` could be run in different context than the `instance`.

Using `event handler`, I am thinking of declaring one and use it like this

```
private void endAsyncItemHandler (IASyncResult ar) {
    HasASyncClass asyncItem = ar.AsyncState as HasASyncClass;
    asyncItem.EndAsync(ar); 
    if (MyEventHandler != null)
        MyEventHandler(this, new EventArgs());    
    //and so on
}
```

Is this good/safe enough?